# SQL Server 2005, counting totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, count

I would like to know how to query a database whereby I can return two sums, the first being the total number of inspections, then a total for each inspector ie, Joe has done a total of 4 inspections but still shows a breakdown of the different levels. I'm new to sql so have included my script so far, but let me know if you need more info.

```
SELECT     InspectorCode AS Inspector, InspectionProcedureName AS [Procedure], COUNT(*) AS     Total
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
AND InspectionProcedureName LIKE '%Inspection%'
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName, InspectorCode
```

I would like to see

```
Inspector   Procedure   Total    InspTotal 
joe         1 - Inspection  1        4
joe         2 - Inspection  3
kit         3 - Inspection  14       14
hugh        1 - Inspection  17       32
hugh        6 - Inspection  15
mike        4 - Inspection  18       18
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about sql server but in oracle following query will give result as you want-

```
SELECT zz.Inspector as Inspector,
       zz.Procedure as Procedure,
       zz.total as total,
       case 
       when zz.c_1 =1 then
       zz.InspTotal 
       else 
       null
       end as InspTotal        
       FROM (SELECT InspectorCode AS Inspector, 
       InspectionProcedureName AS Procedure, 
       COUNT(*) AS     Total ,
       count(*) over(partition by InspectorCode) InspTotal,
       row_number() over( partition by InspectorCode order by InspectionProcedureName) c_1 
FROM   UnitData_Vehicle 
WHERE  (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1) 
       AND InspectionProcedureName LIKE '%Inspection%' 
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName, InspectorCode)zz;
```

please check your `where` condition..
I was checking and working for last desired column only..
as in you question you have not tell anything about conditions...

please comment here if you want clarification on anything in this query..

one more thing -
     i assumed that you want InspTotal column value only once for any InspectorCode code..
am i right??

Comment: +1 interesting, I thought you couldn't use `over` to go outside the group

Comment: thanks for this however it doesn't work with sql, but yes you are right I only would like to see one value per total, or null if no value returned. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Based on @pratik garg's answer, looks like this works in SQL Server:

```
select  InspectorCode as Inspector
,       InspectionProcedureName as Procedure
,       count(*) as Total
,       count(*) over (partition by InspectorCode) as InspTotal
from    UnitData_Vehicle as uv1
where   (datediff(day, InspectionDateTime, getdate()) = 1)
        and InspectionProcedureName like '%Inspection%'
group by 
        InspectorCode
,       Procedure
```

The `count(*) over (partition by InspectorCode)` apparently honors the `where` clause, but does count over multiple groups.  Interesting :)

Comment: Thanks guys, this one works however it is counting how many of each procedure the inspector has done ie Joe has done 2 types of inspection. if possible I would like to see the total of inspections done for each inspector ie Joe has done 4. But thank you for your efforts so far!

Comment: @Tyrone2011: The InspTotal column should show the total inspections for a manager, see [this example at odata](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/104184/)

Answer (score 0):

The following example code runs fine for my database

```
SELECT fiscalmonth,item,fiscalyear
       ,SUM(valuesale)
       ,
(SELECT SUM(valueSale)
FROM inbalance b 
WHERE b.fiscalmonth <= a.fiscalmonth 
and a.fiscalyear =b.fiscalyear 
and a.item = b.item
) AS RunningTotal
FROM inbalance a
WHERE a.item='1101'
AND a.fiscalyear=2011
GROUP BY fiscalmonth,item,fiscalyear
```

So by "translating" my code to your query

```
SELECT     InspectorCode AS Inspector, InspectionProcedureName AS [Procedure], COUNT(*) AS     Total
, (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UnitData_Vehicle b
WHERE a.InspectorCode = b.InspectorCode 
AND b.InspectionProcedureName <=  b.InspectionProcedureName
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName,InspectorCode
) As InspTotal
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle a
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
AND InspectionProcedureName LIKE '%Inspection%'
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName, InspectorCode
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'inspector'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "b.inspector" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "b.InspectionProcedureName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "b.InspectionProcedureName" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Inspector'.

Comment: thanks for that script, looks good, but I have recieved a few errors? any ideas? thanks

Comment: Cheers, sorry but just tried again again this is the error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: It's also fixed, sorry for that.